# Loop on SQL select

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm currently developing a sport forecast application. In this app I have team genders (men/women), sports (football, rugby...) and contest types (world cup...).
Every contest type has a label : world cup for example. A team gender and a sport are also linked.

At the moment I'm doing the delete method for a gender. But I want to check if the gender to delete is linked to a contest type. If so, I'd like to throw an exception. If not, it's safe to delete.

The delete on a gender which is not linked to a contest type works well. But when I try to delete one that is linked, the app loops on a SQL request when trying to fetch the contestType set of the gender :

```
Hibernate: select contesttyp0_.gender as gender3_3_0_, contesttyp0_.id as id1_3_0_, contesttyp0_.id as id1_3_1_, contesttyp0_.gender as gender3_3_1_, contesttyp0_.label as label2_3_1_, contesttyp0_.sport as sport4_3_1_ from contest_type contesttyp0_ where contesttyp0_.gender=?
```

And then I have an error :

```
2020-07-07 09:15:48.301  WARN 28228 --- [io-8086-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1000
2020-07-07 09:15:48.301 ERROR 28228 --- [io-8086-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : null
```

And a lot of :

```
2020-07-07 09:15:48.333  WARN 28228 --- [io-8086-exec-10] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@1fc91d2c<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@2135475200 wrapping Result set representing update count of -1>
```

And finally :

```
java.sql.SQLException: null
```

So here are my entities :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contest_type")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ToString
public class ContestTypeEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String label;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name="gender")
    private GenderEntity gender;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name="sport")
    private SportEntity sport;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gender")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ToString
public class GenderEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String label;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "gender", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ContestTypeEntity> contestTypes;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sport")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class SportEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String label;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sport", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ContestTypeEntity> contestTypes;
}
```

And here is my controller delete method:

```
@DeleteMapping(GET_GENDER_URI)
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteGender(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    Gender gender = this.genderService.getGender(id);
    String message = this.bundle.getString(DELETE_GENDER);
    this.log.debug(message, id);
    this.genderService.delete(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(gender, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}
```

And my service delete method:

```
@Transactional
    public void delete(long id) {

        GenderEntity genderEntity = genderRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> {
            String pattern = this.bundle.getString(GENDER_WRONG_ID);
            String message = MessageFormat.format(pattern, id);
            return new EntityNotFoundException(message);
        });

        Set<ContestTypeEntity> contestTypeEntities = genderEntity.getContestTypes();
        if(contestTypeEntities.size() > 0) {
            String pattern = this.bundle.getString(GENDER_HAS_CONTEST_TYPE_PARENT);
            String message = MessageFormat.format(pattern,id);
            throw new BadRequestDeleteGenderException(message);
        }

        this.genderRepository.deleteById(genderEntity.getId());
    }
```

It's been days I'm on this and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the Sets of contestType in GenderEntity and SportEntity and then made a request in the contestTypeRepository to fetch the contestTypes that have the gender I want to delete.
And it works!

I think that when I wanted to delete the gender, the app wanted to delete also the Set of ContestTypes. Then it goes in this set and sees that the ContestType has a gender. Then goes into this gender and sees that it has a Set of ContestTypes. And so on!